# How to prevent my strings from being translated to other languages than English?

Tags: android, localization, simpledateformat

I am trying to prevent my app from automatically being translated to other languages (such as Bulgarian in my case). I want all of my strings to be in English. I tried setting the timezone to "Europe\London" (because I am in the UK) but that did not quite work. Is there a way how I can ensure that my app's settings (all of them) are not being translated when somebody install my app in other than the UK country?

I am using dates in my app and I am using `SimpleDateFormatter`. I think this is causing the issue of translating some of the strings. So what I did is set the timezone to it as well before using the strings from it like that:

```
public static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
String time = sdf.format(new Date());
mPurchasedDate.setText(day + " " + numDay + " " + mont + " at " + time);
```

But that did not work either.

PS: I have not added any localization in my app. I have only one `strings.xml` folder and the strings there are in English.

Comment: Can you provide some output where you decribe what you currently get and what you expect?

Comment: FYI, you are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want to use a specific `Locale` for `SimpleDateFormat`, use the constructor that takes a `Locale`: [new SimpleDateFormat(String, Locale)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale)):

```
public static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.UK);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Ian. I will test that but from the look of it I should do the trick. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

In order to stick to `English`, you need to specify `Locale.ENGLISH` with the date-time formatting/parsing API. **Anyway, one of the best practices is to [use `Locale` with the formatting/parsing API in every case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65363205/10819573).**

**Modern API:**

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

**Legacy API:**

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Note that the `java.util.Date` object is not a real date-time object like the [modern date-time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html); rather, it represents the milliseconds from the `Epoch of January 1, 1970`. When you print an object of `java.util.Date`, its `toString` method returns the date-time calculated from this milliseconds value. Since `java.util.Date` does not have timezone information, it applies the timezone of your JVM and displays the same. If you need to print the date-time in a different timezone, you will need to set the timezone to `SimpleDateFomrat` and obtain the formatted string from it.

In contrast, modern date-time API has specific classes representing just date, or time or date-time. And, for each of these, there are separate classes for with/without timezone information. Check out the following [table](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html) for an overview of modern date-time types:

[image]

**A quick demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));

        // Print its default format i.e. the value returned by time#toString
        System.out.println(time);

        // Custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(time.format(dtf));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
12:39:07.627763
12:39:07
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

set translatable to false in strings.xml for every string which u want not to be translated into any other language

```
    <string name="account_setup_imap" translatable="false">IMAP</string>
```